# Correlation between two dataframes by row

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, plyr

I have 2 data frames w/ 5 columns and 100 rows each.

```
id       price1      price2     price3     price4     price5
 1         11.22      25.33      66.47      53.76      77.42
 2         33.56      33.77      44.77      34.55      57.42
...
```

I would like to get the correlation of the corresponding rows, basically

```
for(i in 1:100){    
cor(df1[i, 1:5], df2[i, 1:5])    
}
```

but without using a for-loop.  I'm assuming there's someway to use `plyr` to do it but can't seem to get it right.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Depending on whether you want a cool or fast solution you can use either

```
diag(cor(t(df1), t(df2)))
```

which is cool but wasteful (because it actually computes correlations between all rows which you don't really need so they will be discarded) or

```
A <- as.matrix(df1)
B <- as.matrix(df2)
sapply(seq.int(dim(A)[1]), function(i) cor(A[i,], B[i,]))
```

which does only what you want but is a bit more to type.

Comment: +1 That first one is cool. Also, `t(as.matrix(df1))` can become `t(df1)`, etc., since the coercion to matrix takes place implicitly when `t()` is passed a data.frame.

Comment: Ah, great, thanks (this is where my low-level thinking gets me ;)), I'll edit that

Answer (score 8):

I found that `as.matrix` is not required.

Correlations of all pairs of rows between dataframes `df1` and `df2`:

```
sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(i) cor(df1[i,], df2[i,]))
```

and columns:

```
sapply(1:ncol(df1), function(i) cor(df1[,i], df2[,i]))
```

Comment: can I use the same here in m case I want to find the correlation between gene expression and methylation where my gene sets are same for both the data sets or data frame ?